# lightdm startup script to change locale on raspberry pi with curses

Tags: python, linux, raspberry-pi, python-curses

I've written a script that uses python curses to allow me to change the locale (edits `/etc/default/locale`) on the raspberry pi. It has a basic menu that allows me to select the language.

I want to run this script **before the lxde session starts**. I've tried editing the `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` file but when I do, the pi doesn't boot at all, it just has a black screen with a blinking cursor.

Am I approaching this the right way? Is there a better way to run an interactive python curses before lxde starts?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `crontab` in Linux. You could launch the program at booting:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron